# Accessing Hidden Field Value in Jquery

Tags: jquery

My form looks like the following

```
<form class="search_results_section" method="post" name="MainForm" id="MainForm" action="/searchresults.asp" onsubmit="return OnSubmitSearchForm(event, this);">
            <input type="hidden" name="Search" value="">
            <input type="hidden" name="Cat" value="1856">
</form>
```

**I want to get the "Cat" value of Hidden field in a Variable**

I tried using the following but not sure why its not working

```
  var elements =$('#jmenuhide input[name^="Cat"]').val();
      alert(elements);
  var ele=document.MainForm.getElementsByName('Cat').value;
      alert(ele);
```

The alert says "undefined"

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hCuXX/ <- this seems to do it for me. I assume in your code #jmenuhide is wrapped around the form? Instead why not use the #MainForm id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try using this not sure why you need this  #jmenuhide

```
var elements =$('input[name^="Cat"]').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var elements =$('input[name="Cat"]').val();
      alert(elements);
var ele=document.getElementsByName('Cat')[0].value;
      alert(ele);
```

Here's the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gopi1410/NbCNu/

Answer (score 1):

You can get elements in a form by their name also what is `#jmenuhide` have you tried using `#MainForm` instead

```
var elements =$('#MainForm input[name="Cat"]').val();
  alert(elements);
var ele=document.MainForm.Cat.value;
  alert(ele);​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/N82s5/

Answer (score 0):

For that markup, all you need is:

```
var cat = $('input[name="Cat"]').val();
var search = $('input[name="Search"]').val();

alert(cat); // 1856
alert(search); // (empty string)
​
```